# run list of interdependent functions in correct order in python

Tags: python, performance, asynchronous, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say I get a list of classes of length N<20 containing classes in random order that needs to be instantiated. I also have a and a random set of parameters of len N<20.
Ex: classes: [foo, bar, baz,foo2,bar2,baz2], params:[var1,var2,var3]

A random subset of classes sub1= [foo,bar,bar2] can be run with the available parameters, whereas the rest of the classes need the outputs from some method of the classes in sub1 to run.
I guess this whole problem can be phrased with functions rather than classes.

How do I insure that in every case the classes will be instantiated in the correct order, eg without prompting error because they don't have the necessary parameters? Is there a standard way to approach this problem in Python?
To clarify I don't want to reorder them according to a pre-known order, as the nature of the classes and of their dependencies will change in time.

I thought of a solution, but before proceeeding I wanted to check if there was some standard  and more elegant way.
Proposed solution would be something like:

```
#all the classes will have this rough structuure
class cls:
 def __init__(self,mypdict)
   do things
 def update_mypdict():
   mypdict[new_param]=new_param

classes=[foo, bar, baz,foo2,bar2,baz2]
params=[var1,var2,var3]
mypdict={'var1':var1,'var2':var2,'var3':var3}

while len(classes)>0:
 for cls in classes:
  if infer_input_params(cls) is not a subset of mypdict: #assume i do the logic correct
   pass
  else:
   class=cls(params,mypdict)  #i instantiate the class
   class.update_mypdict()
   classes.remove(cls)        # and remove the cls from the class list
```

Comment: It seems you want to reuse the same arguments for different classes. Why do you name `mypdict` as if it is a dict (but it is not)? Is it intended that you pass one argument (that is a list) to each class constructor? Why would `infer_input_params(cls)` have a different result the next time you call it on the same `cls`? I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include class.update_mypdict(), also corrected the nature of mypdict to be a dictionary. basically I want to add the new parameters coming from every class that i instantiate into mypdict, so that on the next while loop some more functions can run.

Comment: The class constructor in your example expects `mydict` as parameter. How would you decide the arguments to pass? Can you give a completely concrete example and what you expect to happen?